# Return different value from function depending on suffix

Tags: python, tuples

Kind of similar to a class, but should also work inside a class. I'm not sure if it's possible, and not sure the correct keywords to search for, so apologies if there's already an answer.

For example, I mean like this -

```
def location():
    x = 5
    y = 0
    z = 0
    return x,y,z
```

Then by typing location().x, you'd get the number 5. It'd be a lot better using `location().x` instead of `location()[0]` in my opinion.

Edit: I'm asking for this way instead of a class as you may want to have it inside a class, something like `objectInfo( object ).getLocation().x`

Comment: What is the benefit of something like this over actually defining a class?

Comment: Because this way you can put it inside a class. In the example above, you could have getObjectInfo( objectName ).location().x, I'm not sure if it'd be the correct way but I quite like the idea of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>>
>>> XYZ = namedtuple('XYZ', ['x', 'y', 'z'])
>>>
>>> def location():
...     return XYZ(5, 0, 0)
...
>>> location().x
5
```

using `namedtuple`, you can still access the values using indexing `[..]`:

```
>>> location()[0]
5
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you use Python 3.3+, you can also use [`types.SimpleNamespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace):

```
>>> from types import SimpleNamespace
>>> def location():
...     return SimpleNamespace(x=5, y=0, z=0)
...
>>> location().x
5
```

Otherwise, use following class (which came from the above `SimpleNamespace` link):

```
class SimpleNamespace:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
    def __repr__(self):
        keys = sorted(self.__dict__)
        items = ("{}={!r}".format(k, self.__dict__[k]) for k in keys)
        return "{}({})".format(type(self).__name__, ", ".join(items))
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.__dict__ == other.__dict__
```

Comment: I was just going to suggest this.

Comment: Ah thanks, that works great, is setting the named tuple earlier in the code the only way though?

Comment: @Peter, Yes, you should define it before you use it. Alternatively you can use `types.SimpleNamespace` if you use Pyhton 3.3+: `from types import SimpleNamespace; .... return SimpleNamespace(x=5, y=0, z=0)`

Comment: You could, inefficiently, redefine the named tuple each time `location()` is called, but you have to define a class *somewhere*.

Comment: Ah right thanks, I just tried chepners suggestion and it works alright ('return namedtuple('XYZ', ['x', 'y', 'z',])(5,0,0)' if you fancy adding it to the answer), I'll test it out for speed later on

Comment: @Peter, Which version of Python are you using? If you use Python 3.3+, try [types.SimpleNamespace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace) as I mentioned in previous comment.

Comment: @Peter, BTW, you can also specify attributes as a single string separated by space: `return namedtuple('XYZ', 'x y z')(5, 0, 0)` (not efficient as chepner commented)

Comment: I believe it's the 2.7 python I'm on, and I'm just curious, how inefficient is that way? I quite like warvariuc's answer as it'll easily fit everything with little effort, just weighing up which way might be better :)

Comment: @Peter, If you follow the link in my previous comment, you will see similar solution (with extra `__repr__`, `__eq__`).

Comment: @Peter, FYI, here's a timeit result (Python 2.7.8 64bit, Windows 7): http://pastebin.com/wsjhkq8P

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't checked the link with not being on 3.3, but it seems to work even better than the 'Bunch' class :P  And thanks for all the help haha, I'm surprised the efficiency is that much worse

Comment: @Peter, If this helped you, you can tell the community so by [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5235).

Comment: Was about to say I was going to pick it aha, might be worth throwing in that link or the formula it links to for anyone else coming across this page :)

Comment: Hey, just got another quick question - is it possible at all to make it so you can pass arguments through those letters?

Comment: @Peter, I don't get what you mean. Could you post a separated question with input and expected output?

Comment: Didn't think it was worth an extra question, if you think it'd be hard to do then I'll post one up. I just meant like you might have `location.x()` by default (like a class and function, although this would be using the namespace methods as it's within a function). Then for example you could have .x( object2 ) which could perform a relative calculation to the other object. (location isn't the best example for this but you should get the idea)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a ["bunch"](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52308-the-simple-but-handy-collector-of-a-bunch-of-named/):

```
>>> class Bunch(object):
...     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
...             self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
... 
>>> def location():
...     return Bunch(x=5, y=0, z=0)
... 
>>> location().x
5
>>> location().y
0
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, works great, falsetru's method is really good but this way seems a lot better :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as a matrix

def (x,y,z):
x=1
y=7
z=10``
return A=[x,y,z]

and after you can take the numpers with this way A[1] for x .
I thing you understand what i mean, and this is a way to have your variables in a series

Comment: That's not even valid Python, let alone a return value with attributes.

Comment: I get what he means haha, I'm looking for an alternative way to numbers in square brackets though :)